# Simulate a "Click" with Python

Tags: python, buttonclick

I have read in all topics but is not so clear how to simulate a click in python. I'm using `requests` but I didn't understand how to simulate it.

The code that I need to "click" is that:

```
<div class="container"> <a class="brand" href=url> <img src="logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        <div class="page-container">
            <form class='addf' action="" method="post">
                <h1>url server</h1>


                <p>

                Welcome to url server!
                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="Username"  id="Username" readonly placeholder="Click to generate your username...">
                <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="32bbba790d2a75a5dafec2ec6c3bbc19" />

                <button name='urlline' type="submit">Generate now!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: try selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1):

If you know which action the form posts to, you may be able to do it by posting directly combined with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

The line: `<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="32bbba790d2a75a5dafec2ec6c3bbc19" />` is important, as this hash was most likely generated when the page was served. This is done to combat DDoS, e.g someone spamming requests to the form-action. So in order for the webserver to accept your request, you will have to inspect this value and and pass it along your POST request.

You could do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://some-url/"                              # replace with target URL
r  = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    form = bs.findAll("form", {"class": "addf"})[0]   # find the form

    inputs = form.findAll("input")                    # find the input-fields
    hash = None
    for input in inputs:
        if input.get("name") == "formid":             # find the hash
            hash = input.get("value")

    if hash:
        action = "createusername"                     # replace with target action
        res = requests.post(url + action, data={
            # ... other parameters, if any
            "formid" : hash
        })
        print(res)
```

You may need to refine how Beautiful Soup searches the HTML, e.g if multiple elements have `class="addf"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome' developers tools to observe the network traffic, then use the requests library to simulate the http request.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
import requests as req
import random
import math
username = "";    
payload = {'Username': username,'password': 'password'}
resp = req.post(url, data=payload)
```

thank you! :)